# ORB SLAM 3 - Implementation

Tags: slam

I'm trying to run ORB-SLAM3 and I keep getting the following error messages:
ORB-SLAM3 Copyright (C) 2017-2020 Carlos Campos, Richard Elvira, Juan J. Gómez, José M.M. Montiel and Juan D. Tardós, University of Zaragoza.
ORB-SLAM2 Copyright (C) 2014-2016 Raúl Mur-Artal, José M.M. Montiel and Juan D. Tardós, University of Zaragoza.
This program comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY;
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions. See LICENSE.txt.

Input sensor was set to: Stereo

Loading ORB Vocabulary. This could take a while...
Vocabulary loaded!

Creation of new map with id: 0
Creation of new map with last KF id: 0
Seq. Name:

Camera Parameters:

- fx: 435.20468139648438
- fy: 435.20468139648438
- cx: 367.45172119140625
- cy: 252.20085144042969
- bf: 47.906394958496094
- k1: 0
- k2: 0
- p1: 0
- p2: 0
- fps: 20
- color order: RGB (ignored if grayscale)

ORB Extractor Parameters:

- Number of Features: 1200
- Scale Levels: 8
- Scale Factor: 1.2000000476837158
- Initial Fast Threshold: 20
- Minimum Fast Threshold: 7

Depth Threshold (Close/Far Points): 3.8527247905731201

### Failed to load image at: /home/yz2qmq/ORB_SLAM3/V1_01_easy/MH01/mav0/cam0/data/1403636579763555584.png
./euroc_eval_examples.sh: line 16: 20460 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./Examples/Stereo/stereo_euroc ./Vocabulary/ORBvoc.txt ./Examples/Stereo/EuRoC.yaml "$pathDatasetEuroc"/MH01 ./Examples/Stereo/EuRoC_TimeStamps/MH01.txt "$pathDatasetEuroc"/MH02 ./Examples/Stereo/EuRoC_TimeStamps/MH02.txt "$pathDatasetEuroc"/MH03 ./Examples/Stereo/EuRoC_TimeStamps/MH03.txt "$pathDatasetEuroc"/MH04 ./Examples/Stereo/EuRoC_TimeStamps/MH04.txt "$pathDatasetEuroc"/MH05 ./Examples/Stereo/EuRoC_TimeStamps/MH05.txt dataset-MH01_to_MH05_stereo

Evaluation of MAchine Hall trajectory with Stereo sensor
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "evaluation/evaluate_ate_scale.py", line 151, in 
second_list = associate.read_file_list(args.second_file, False)
File "/home/yz2qmq/ORB_SLAM3/evaluation/associate.py", line 64, in read_file_list
file = open(filename)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'f_dataset-MH01_to_MH05_stereo.txt'
Launching V102 with Monocular-Inertial sensor
num_seq = 1
file name: dataset-V102_monoi
Loading images for sequence 0...LOADED!

I made the changes required in the euroc_eval_examples.sh and change it by the dataset path!

Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Had the Same prob here.
I just had the path and its syntax all messed UP.

Try to run the whole thing with this command:
./Examples/Monocular/mono_euroc ./Vocabulary/ORBvoc.txt ./Examples/Monocular/EuRoC.yaml "$pathDatasetEuroc"/MH01 ./Examples/Monocular/EuRoC_TimeStamps/MH01.txt dataset-MH01_mono

And where it says "$pathDatasetEuroc" make sure you put the right path before   MH01, in which there should only be the mav0 folder.
In your case should be /home/yz2qmq/ORB_SLAM3/V1_01_easy

----> ./Examples/Monocular/mono_euroc ./Vocabulary/ORBvoc.txt ./Examples/Monocular/EuRoC.yaml /home/yz2qmq/ORB_SLAM3/V1_01_easy/MH01 ./Examples/Monocular/EuRoC_TimeStamps/MH01.txt dataset-MH01_mono

That at least worked for me.

It is exactly the same thing as running ./euroc_examples.sh, and you will realize it easily if you open and read briefly euroc_examples.sh.

(This btw is a guide which actually worked for me only after following it blindly :( https://www.ybliu.com/2020/07/ORB-SLAM3-demo.html)